# Does anyone know of a stellar map that gives the distance between the nearest systems?

Tags: science-fiction, worldbuilding-resources, map-making

[What im looking is for something like this](http://www.solstation.com/stars/s10ly1.jpg) but with more stars

Comment: While this is falls in the worldbuilding realm, I think that Astronomy.SE might host more experts who could give sound answers.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this belongs on Astronomy Stack Exchange, not Worldbuilding Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just do it yourself, using a handy Stellar Coordinate catalog like
http://www.johnstonsarchive.net/astro/nearstar.html

and the tool at
http://www.neoprogrammics.com/stars/distance_between_two_stars/index.php

As there are more than 84 million catalogued stars already, a complete distance map between them would comprise a graph of 7 quadrillion lines, making a somewhat large and complex object.

Better to construct your own, using exactly that subset of stars you are interested in.

Comment: https://xkcd.com/1162/ seems appropriate for the 7 quadrillion lines